# Is there a way to split up each line of a file into an element of an array | PHP

Tags: php, arrays, file, line, explode

Straight up: No, it's not the "usual question" and yes - I've read the other StackOverflow articles regarding this topic and they didn't help me.

If you create the array within a file and look at the output:

```
$names = ["test123", "test!?", "test"];
var_dump($names);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "test123"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "test!?"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "test"
}
```

... which is completely correct. 3 elements each a string.

BUT if you read the lines of a file via explode and input them into an array:

```
$names = explode("\n", file_get_contents('list.txt'));
var_dump($names);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
" string(8) "test123
  [1]=>
" string(7) "test!?
  [2]=>
  string(4) "test"
}
```

... which differs from the first one as these are all strings, but (excluding the last one) having one character more each + not being quoted as the array above.

**So my question:** How can I read all the lines of a file into elements of an array, with the exact spelling of the first example I've delivered? I need the exact format as a "normal array" for the further programme, but I can't get it working :)

Comment: Are you working on a Windows machine? Then newlines are marked with \r\n and the \r part remains

Comment: Safest way would be to go with the answer by heithem moumni

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you can use this line of code

```
$lines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```